# Html iframe external website links not working

Tags: web, iframe, hyperlink, adobe, portfolio

so i created a simple portfolio with adobe portfolio
i did put the site in a html file in an iframe
site is showing up but i cant open the external links from the portfolio site

this is my adobe portfolio site - https://360studios.myportfolio.com/
this is my html file with iframe - https://360studios.at/3d/portfolio/
if you click on the thumbs the links are not opening

thx for the help!

regards, sebastian

---

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.